# How to find the deepest dict-level of a multilevel python dict?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

For example, if we have a dict like `{a: {b: c}, d: e}`, then the max level for this dict is 2.

I've been thinking about the method to find the max level of an arbitrary dict for 2 days, but didn't figure out a solution.

How to do that?

Comment: So you are looking for an integer here? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, I'm trying to solve the eight queen puzzle, with the representation of dictionary trees. Like, `result={(1,2):{(3.4):{...}}}`, so if a sub_item of result have the depth of 8, then it is one of the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion:

```
def nested_depth(d):
    if not isinstance(d, dict):
        return 0
    if not d:
        return 1
    return 1 + max(nested_depth(v) for v in d.values())
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I should use recursion here, but my head is totally a mess when dealing with this problem. Thanks, I'll study your answer through.